# Page displays unformatted text when using WebView within a Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Managed to get some things working. An app I am working on displays a web view like I want it to in a fragment, but the fragment just displays unformatted plain text whatever HTML styling I put in the string (the text is correct though). Any ideas what I have done wrong?

The fragment (ignore the naming of files, that will be fixed, like textviewabout):

```
public static class AboutMeFragment extends Fragment {
 public AboutMeFragment() {
 }

 @Override

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aboutme,
        container, false);
      WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textviewabout);
      String summary = (getString(R.string.about_me));
      webView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
      return rootView;
 }
}
```

In strings:

```
    <string name="about_me">"<html><body><b>This is a test of bold</b></body></html>"</string>
```

and about me.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$AboutMeFragment" >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/textviewabout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical" />
     </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) documentation you will see that the `getString` method strips formatting information from the String. Since Android treats HTML as styling information. If you want to return HTML from your strings file you will need to do the following;

```
<string name="about_me"><![CDATA[
<html><body><b>This is a test of bold</b></body></html>
]]></string>
```

Android will not strip the HTML from your text and you should get the bold HTML you are after.